# Alternate Numbering rows if the data is the different

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-server-2014, gaps-and-islands

Current Data:

```
|LotNumber |ItemNumber |ItemName
|76        |1          |WidgetRight
|76        |1          |WidgetLeft
|76        |2          |WidgetRight
|76        |2          |WidgetLeft
|76        |7          |WidgetRight
|76        |7          |WidgetLeft
|76        |9          |WidgetRight
|76        |10         |WidgetRight
|76        |10         |WidgetLeft
|80        |3          |WidgetRight
|80        |3          |WidgetLeft
|80        |7          |WidgetRight
|80        |7          |WidgetLeft
|80        |11         |WidgetRight
|80        |31         |WidgetRight
```

Need to add a column that alternates between 1 and 2 every time the ItemNumber changes

```
|LotNumber |ItemNumber |ItemName       |NewField
|76        |1          |WidgetRight    |1
|76        |1          |WidgetLeft     |1
|76        |2          |WidgetRight    |2
|76        |2          |WidgetLeft     |2
|76        |7          |WidgetRight    |1
|76        |7          |WidgetLeft     |1
|76        |9          |WidgetRight    |2
|76        |10         |WidgetRight    |1
|76        |10         |WidgetLeft     |1
|80        |3          |WidgetRight    |2
|80        |3          |WidgetLeft     |2
|80        |7          |WidgetRight    |1
|80        |7          |WidgetLeft     |1
|80        |11         |WidgetRight    |2
|80        |31         |WidgetRight    |1
```

Current Code not working ...

```
DECLARE @LastLine Varchar(1)

SELECT ItemNumber, ItemName,
CASE WHEN ItemNumber <> LAG (ItemNumber, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY LotNumber ORDER BY LotNumber, ItemNumber )
THEN
    CASE WHEN @LastLine = '1'
    THEN  '2'
    ELSE  '1'
    END 
END AS LastLine
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `dense_rank()` and arithmetics:

```
select t.*,
    1 + (dense_rank() over(order by lotnumber, itemnumber) + 1) % 2 as newfield
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b6a9901de851b91b8403e9d60b76014)**